# Issues with NSOutlineView and ImageAndTextCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm having an `NSOutlineView` with items (and children in it).

Here's the cell modification code :

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[JQPage class]])
    {
        [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"doc_empty_icon&16"] size:16.0];
    }
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[JQElement class]])
    {
        [cell setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"brackets_icon&16"] size:16.0];
    }   
}
```

---

And here's a visual example of what I need :

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about pushing the children to the right. You might have to overwrite som e class function.

You can swap the image to a white version when the item is selected. I don't know if NSOutlineView support Automatic Black/white swap, but if it does you have to set the background style with something like

```
-(void)setBackgroundStyle:(NSBackgroundStyle)backgroundStyle {


     [super setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLight];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for regarding the image is NSImage setTemplate. From the docs,

> Cocoa cells take advantage of the nature of template images—that is, their simplified color scheme and use of transparency—to improve the appearance of the corresponding control in each of its supported states.

In this case the image will be swapped with its negative on selection.